# Boostrap image responsive in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

It's first time when i use Codeigniter, so I tried to work with Bootstrap. I knew Bootstrap has a class for images: `img-responsive`, but you can only use a parameter in `img() codeigniter function`. So , i tried something like this:

```
$logo = array(
        'src' => 'assets/images/logo.png',
        'class' => 'img-responsive',
    );
```

Then i included $logo into img($logo). If I check View Source of page, link looks like:

```
<img src="http://localhost/assets/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
```

but image is not responsive. Any idea ?

Comment: Is the rest of the page responsive? Did you set all the required metas?

Comment: Yes. And I checked twice name of included files.

Comment: What version of bootsrap are you using? You might have bumped into https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10690

Comment: v3.3.6. I just downloaded !

Comment: the img tag seems correct. is there anything around it that might break responsiveness? maybe upload the view-source to http://pastebin.com/?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gA66jv9Y

Comment: I think i found it. Remove the 'navbar-brand' class. It has `.navbar-brand {height: 50px;}`. So forcing height 50 breaks responsiveness

Comment: well, i'm out of ideas here... you can try the img code outside any `nav` tags (these have a lot of css). Just put it in a `div` directly inside `<div class="container">`

Comment: Seems to work in container ...

Comment: Is it not working???

Comment: no @devpro ... it's strange

Comment: Just for test.... style="width:100%;height: auto;display:block;".  Write inline

Comment: If bootstrap included fine inline will work if still same than it means something wrong in yur html

Comment: I found a solution: Remove `class='img-responsive'` and set `height` . Now it's responsive !:)